# Filtering collections in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

Hello I am running a search of a backbone collection, the current string I am searching is

> Project Number

This should return 2 results however it only ever shows 1 result, I cannot understand why, below is the code that I using,

The code the runs when adding search parameters,

```
updateSearchFilter: function(e) {
    var self = this;
    this.collection.each(this.filterHide, this);
    if($(e.currentTarget).val() === "")
    {
        this.collection.each(this.filterShow, this);
    }

    var activeLabels = $(".labels").find(".inactive");
    $.each(activeLabels, function(key, index){
        switch($(index).attr("id"))
        {
            case "pending":
                status = "7";
                self.filterDetails.states["pending"] = false;
            break;

            case "completed":
                status = "5";
                self.filterDetails.states["complete"] = false;
            break;

            case "archived":
                status = "3";
                self.filterDetails.states["archived"] = false;
            break;

            case "active":
                status = "1";
                self.filterDetails.states["active"] = false;
            break;
        }
    });

    var visible = this.collection.search($(e.currentTarget).val(), this.filterDetails.states);
    if (visible !== undefined) {
        visible.each(this.filterShow, this);
    }
},
```

So the above code, hides the idividual results on the first key press, is then loops through an array of jquery objects and re-assigns some values in an object - this is done so we can work out what filters we need to search through.

We then run our search code,

```
ProjectCollection.prototype.search = function(searchTerm, filters) {

  var pattern;
  console.log(filters);
  pattern = new RegExp(searchTerm, "gi");

  if (filters.active && filters.archived) {
    if (searchTerm === "") {
      return this;
    }
    return _(this.filter(function(data) {
      return pattern.test(data.get("project_name") + data.get("client_name"));
    }));


  } else if (filters.active) {
    if (searchTerm === "") {
      return this.active();
    }
    return _(this.active().filter(function(data) {
      return pattern.test(data.get("project_name") + data.get("client_name"));
    }));


  } else if (filters.pending) {
    console.log("hello");
    if (searchTerm === "") {
      return this.pending();
    }
    return _(this.pending().filter(function(data) {
      return pattern.test(data.get("project_name") + data.get("client_name"));
    }));


  } else if (filters.archived) {
    if (searchTerm === "") {
      return this.archived();
    }
    return _(this.archived().filter(function(data) {
      return pattern.test(data.get("project_name") + data.get("client_name"));
    }));


  } else if (filters.complete) {
    if (searchTerm === "") {
      return this.complete();
    }
    return _(this.complete().filter(function(data) {
      return pattern.test(data.get("project_name") + data.get("client_name"));
    }));
  }
};

ProjectCollection.prototype.archived = function() {
  return new ProjectCollection(this.where({
    status: '3'
  }));
};

ProjectCollection.prototype.active = function() {
  return new ProjectCollection(this.where({
    status: '1'
  }));
};

ProjectCollection.prototype.pending = function() {
  return new ProjectCollection(this.where({
    status: '7'
  }))
};

ProjectCollection.prototype.complete = function() {
  return new ProjectCollection(this.where({
    status: '5'
  }));
}
```

Now what I should be getting back is 2 results,

> Project Number 1 & Project Number 2

However I only every get one result on this search term, Project Number 1 has the status of "Archived" and Project Number 2 has the status of "Pending". However I never seem to get go into the pending portion of the logic (above) even though `filters.pending = true`;

How can I make sure that I get all the matches for each status returned?

Comment: If you're never seeing the "hello" message in the console, then clearly `filters.active` must be evaluating `true`. (The value of `filters.archived` is irrelevant to whether or not the pending case executes.) Since you're echoing the `filters` object to the console, look and see what `filters.active` is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting state of your filter individually, you could keep all filter status keys in an array. For example, your user want to filter for `active`, `complete` and `pending` so you would have an array of `['1','5','7']`

So when you filter for relevant statuses you could do by

```
// filterModes is ['1', '5', '7'];
collection.filter(function(model){
    return filterModes.indexOf(model.status) !== -1;
}
```

The rest should be simpler for you now

Note that `collection.filter()` and `collection.where()` return array and array may or may not have `filter()` and definitely don't have `where()` so be wary about chaining your function call